# AlertDialog setItems without onclick

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener, android-dialog

I have created an AlertDialog and added Items from a list with:

```
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

This works, but the Problem is I don´t want the dialog to be closed if I click on an item.
Is there an possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 builder.setItems(items, null);
```

Will usually do the trick with an AlertDialog, you should check the source code to confirm.

Comment: Thank you, thats way easier as I thought it is :D Sometimes I´m just blind